# Draw rectangles like voting on a heatmap

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I want to create mat files in opencv and initialize them to zero(all the pixels to be black). Thus I use
for initialization purpose:

```
Mat img = Mat::zeros(image.rows, image.cols, CV_8UC1);
```

After that I have got some rectangles with locations inside that image and I want to draw the correspondent regions of rectangle white. How is it possible to draw a region in mat file?

I have the following function to draw rects. However I want to draw all the rectangle not just the boundaries.

```
static Mat image_draw(Mat image, vector<Rect> rect, CvScalar  color){

for(int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
{
    Point pt1(rect[i].x + rect[i].width, rect[i].y + rect[i].height);
    Point pt2(rect[i].x, rect[i].y);
    rectangle(image, pt1, pt2, color, 5, 8, 0);
}
return image;
```

}

The exact thing I want to do is to create a heat map for my rectangles so the overlapped bounding boxes to have higher values(close to 255) that the simple non-overlapped rectangles. I change thickness:

```
img =  image_draw( img, rects,  cvScalar(255, 102, 255, 0), -1);
```

Variable rects contains from 0 to 10 rectangle. I want somehow to aggregate the rectangles drawing. Not just redraw again the rectangles.

If I want to functionize it, is somwthing like that: EDIT final solution:

```
static Mat heatmap2(Mat image1, vector<Rect> faces, CvScalar  color, int thickness) {

cv::Mat heatmap(image1.rows, image1.cols, CV_8U,cv::Scalar(0));

for(int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
{
    cv::Mat temp(image1.rows, image1.cols , CV_8U, cv::Scalar(0));
    Point pt1(faces[i].x + faces[i].width, faces[i].y + faces[i].height);
    Point pt2(faces[i].x, faces[i].y);
    rectangle(temp, pt1, pt2, color, thickness, 8, 0);
    heatmap+=temp;
}

return heatmap;
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
    cv::Mat heatmap(200,300,CV_8U,cv::Scalar(0));
    {
        cv::Mat temp(200,300,CV_8U,cv::Scalar(0));
        cv::Rect r(10,20,30,30);
        cv::rectangle(temp,r,cv::Scalar(100),-1);
        heatmap+=temp;
    }
    {
        cv::Mat temp(200,300,CV_8U,cv::Scalar(0));
        cv::Rect r(20,25,30,30);
        cv::rectangle(temp,r,cv::Scalar(100),-1);
        heatmap+=temp;
    }
    cv::imshow("Heatmap",heatmap);
    cv::waitKey();
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: If I want to functinonize it?

Comment: Well, think about it, this is a trivial question. Very basic stuff (functions and classes).

Comment: What  changes if I want to add color to heat map?

Comment: CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(blue,green,red)

Comment: Working but quite unoptimal to add the whole matrix when you only need a subportion

Comment: Do you need help for optimization? I could spend some time on it, too.

Answer (score 2):

From the official OpenCV Documentation (check [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#rectangle)), "**Thickness** of lines that make up the rectangle. Negative values, like `CV_FILLED` , mean that the function has to draw a filled rectangle."

So give thickness a negative value like -

```
rectangle(image, pt1, pt2, color, -1, 8, 0);
```

**UPDATE**
Use these lines in your code,

```
for(int i=0; i < rect.size(); i++)
            for( int y = rect[i].y; y < rect[i].y + rect[i].height; y++ )
                for( int x = rect[i].x; x < rect[i].x + rect[i].width; x++ )
                {
                    image.at<uchar>(y,x) =
                            saturate_cast<uchar>( image.at<uchar>(y,x) + 50 );
                }
```

Here each `Rect` will increase the intensity by 50, and when it reaches 255, it will stay 255.

**Input Image**

[image]

**Output Image**

[image]

**2 overlapping rect**

[image]

Comment: Yea this is an option. However the exact thing I want to do is to create a heat map for my rectangles so the overlapped bounding boxes to have higher values that the simple non-overlapped rectangles.

Comment: How are you calculating the "higher values"? Do you already have a `Mat` object of `Rect` size which you want to paste on your image or you want to calculate it?

Comment: I mean if I have two overlapped bounding boxes I want the first draw a rectangle a gray-value 50 for example and the second overlapped rectangle add a gray-value 50 in order the overlapped region to be whiter than the non-overlapped region. Basically i ve got multiple classifiers and I want to locate where the classifiers decision overlapped.

Answer (score 1):

Just a slight modification to your code should work:

```
static void draw_rectangles(Mat image, vector<Rect> faces) {

cv::Mat heatmap(image.rows, image.cols, CV_8U,cv::Scalar(0));

for(int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
{
    cv::Mat temp = heatmat(faces[i]); // gives you a submatrix of your heatmap pointing at the location of your rectangle
    temp += 10; // add 10 grey levels to the existing values. This also modifies heatmap as side-effect
}
imshow("heatmap", heatmap);
waitKey(0);
```

Comment: What  changes if I want to add color to heat map?

Comment: Use a lookup table [`cv::lut`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=lut#cv.LUT)

Comment: Is it possible to clarify your comment?

Comment: check the doc on the hyperlink. Lookup tables are useful to associate a certain grey-level pixel value to a BGR triplet, so you can visualise your 'heatmap' as a real heatmap, i.e. redish for the highest values in your matrix